# String vs list membership check

Tags: python, string, list

So i'm wondering why this:

```
'alpha' in 'alphanumeric'
```

is `True`, but

```
list('alpha') in list('alphanumeric')
```

is `False`.

Why does `x in s` succeed when `x` is a substring of `s`, but `x in l` doesn't when `x` is a sub*list* of `l`?

Comment: If you print `list('alphanumeric')`, you'll notice that it doesn't have a sublist containing `'alpha'` in it.

Comment: @tdelaney But it does contain the sublist `['a','l','p','h','a']`. If `in` checked for sublists and not just membership then `list('alpha') in list('alphanumeric')` would indeed return `True`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `list` function with any iterable, a new list object will be created with all the elements from the iterable as individual elements in the list.

In your case, strings are valid Python iterables, so

```
>>> list('alpha')
['a', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a']
>>> list('alphanumeric')
['a', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'u', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'c']
```

So, you are effectively checking if one list is a sublist of another list.

In Python only Strings have the `in` operator to check if one string is part of another string. For all other collections, you can only use individual members. Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in),

> The operators `in` and `not in` test for collection membership. `x in s` evaluates to true if `x` is a member of the collection `s`, and false otherwise. `x not in s` returns the negation of `x in s`. The collection membership test has traditionally been bound to sequences; an object is a member of a collection if the collection is a sequence and contains an element equal to that object. However, it make sense for many other object types to support membership tests without being a sequence. In particular, dictionaries (for keys) and sets support membership testing.
>
> **For the list and tuple types, `x in y` is true if and only if there exists an index `i` such that `x == y[i]` is true.**
>
> **For the Unicode and string types, `x in y` is true if and only if `x` is a substring of `y`.** An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`. Note, `x` and `y` need not be the same type; consequently, `u'ab'` in `'abc'` will return `True`. Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `""` in `"abc"` will return `True`.

Answer (score 4):

`list`s determine membership if an item is equal to one of the list members.

`str`s determine whether string **a** is in string **b** if a substring of **b** is equal to **a**.

Answer (score 4):

For the second one you are asking if

`['a', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a'] in ['a', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'u', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'c']`

and there is no sub-list in the second list only characters.

`['a', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a'] in [['a', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a'], ['b', 'e', 't', 'a']]`

would be true

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are looking for the fact that `string` and `list` has different implementations of `__contains__` magic method.

[https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**contains**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

This is why `'alpha' in 'alphanumeric'` is True, but

`list('alpha') in list('alphanumeric')` is False

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should try `issubset` method.

```
>>> set('alpha').issubset(set('alphanumeric'))
True
```

although `set('alpha')` returns `set(['a', 'p', 'l', 'h'])`, and `set('alphanumeric')`, `set(['a', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'h', 'm', 'l', 'n', 'p', 'r', 'u'])`.

set method makes a list ignoring repetetive elements.